# Why RecyclerView.ViewHolder has to be a static?

Tags: android

Since we are not setting tags on views and views get automatically recycled, so chances of adapter leaks are significantly low. So why it has to declared `static`.
Also since we have made it `static` we can't use the adapter class variables in the holder, and we have to make interfaces for possibly any action we need to perform on views.

From what I researched, is it for making the `View` object references static?

**Update:**

*Codepath tutorials
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView*
*Android developer documents
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html*

declare the ViewHolder as static classes.

Comment: "So why it has to declared static" -- who says that it has to be declared `static`?

Comment: Most implementation which I have seen implement it to be static like from codepath tutorials  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView or even google developer trainings here https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Just because some code samples show it implemented as `static` does not mean that it "has to be static", as you have in your question title. Would you say that "code comments have to be in English"? After all, both samples that you point to have code comments in English.

Comment: So, it won't have any performance issues, right sir?

Comment: I would not expect that there would be performance issues here. As you suggest in your question, everything is self-contained from a memory management standpoint, so there should be no memory leaks (or, if there are, that would suggest a bug somewhere). Other performance characteristics, like CPU speed, should not be affected in any significant fashion whether the classes are standalone Java classes, `static` nested classes, or inner classes.